# What are the Pros and Cons of Working for Family?

Tags: job-offer, startup, family

My brother has a tech start up idea, he has offered me a position on his venture doing product management, and is willing to double my current salary on the bases that I relocate to North America and become his right hand man after getting funding. He has told me that he is looking for someone to potentially become the COO of the tech start up that he can trust and has given me till the weekend to think about it. I am not sure if I should take it up.

Pros of working for my brother:

- Double the salary
- Relocate to N. America, become more independent and better living conditions than the UK etc

Cons of working for my brother:

- I don't know if we will work well together, he is a very head strong character. We have fallen out in the past over pieces of work.
- He is a family member, I have worked with family members in the past and they usually end up expecting you to be more committed than an ordinary employee to the point that it becomes overbearing.
- He hasn't yet got start up funding, but is expecting me to work weekends/my spare time for free to show how committed I am. So, I am currently thinking that he will probably expect me to be a workaholic once employed not respecting work/life balance.

What are the pros and cons of working for a family member?

Comment: Right now this is a very broad question, you may want to consider focusing it a bit more on a generalized question- pro's and con's of working for family, for instance.     And also, "...is expecting me to work weekends/my spare time for free to show how committed I am." You can work for money, you can work for equity, but don't work for free.

Comment: @MackM. yeah you are right, I am not sure how to make it more concise without describing the situation. I guess what I am trying to say, does family and business mix healthily?

Comment: Some family businesses have worked wonders and been great for the people involved; some have ended with family members killing each other. Ultimately the same rules apply: do you trust them, do you have reason to trust them in a work/business setting (money), do you have reason to believe they can deliver on their promises, what are the risks, what is your past relevant experience with this person, what experience do they have that would indicate they would be successful, etc. From the sounds of it they want a co-founder, but aren't offering equity, and that's usually a serious problem.

Comment: He is willing to offer equity (plus salary when funded) - sweat equity which will be 3%, I am not interested in equity either way, since seeing a return would probably be unlikely for most start ups.

Comment: I don't really hate my current company, but the culture of expecting everyone to be a workaholic needs to decrease. I have seen this in other start ups, just really find it annoying when employers do not respect people's time outside of working hours, since doing a good job during working hours takes a lot out of you, so unless it's paid and consented overtime it should not be expected and is exploitation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The phrase "unique challenges" is precisely how I see it. It COULD work, but it's the exception (in my observation and experience) rather than the rule.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have taken your point on board, not going to take up his offer. Just a general point. Thank you for your advice as usual.

Comment: *[he] is expecting me to work weekends/my spare time for free to show how committed I am* - Stop your pro/con analysis right here; you have things to do on the weekends and can't work for free.

Comment: Officially declined his offer, he was ok about it and told me that I should do something I was comfortable with doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget "family" for a moment.

Would you do this if it were someone else? Would you actually work for free on the vague promise of a doubled salary?

This isn't an advice site, per se. But mine is that you shouldn't touch this with a 10-foot pole. Look at your own list of cons.

I think you already know that it wouldn't work out well and are hoping for some validation. If so, have mine.

I love my family but I wouldn't work for them for any amount. It muddy's the water and compromises both relationships (professional and personal).  I had my brother work for me one time about 25 years ago, in sales. It changed how we saw each other because our roles had changed.

Lastly, I honestly believe you're being used. It's very common with startups with the lofty promises with no basis for them.  Why you? Is it because you're the best or because he can get something from you that he couldn't from someone local, like free labor?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was looking for advice, seems like a big decision for me. He says he wants to help me improve my quality of life, and has told me that he is doing me a 'favour' given that I only have 14 months project management experience by giving me the salary of somebody senior. That alone basically puts me off, because right now I feel as though it will be hanging over my head and would never feel like an equal. At the same time I am not sure if I am being cynical by assuming that may happen. No I wouldn't work for equity - i.e. free, I have told him this already.

Comment: What happened with your brother our of interest?

Comment: I had to let him go because he wasn't working. Ironically, it's turned out to be a pattern in his life. As to your brother, you won't be an equal, period. He's made that perfectly clear. He's an older brother, isn't he?

Comment: Yeah he is, about 10 years older. How did you know?

Comment: My brother is older and I have many children. Older siblings (in my experience) typically see the younger ones through that lens and it rarely changes. Everything you've said leads me to believe that's how he sees you. You are by definition subordinate in his eyes. He will probably always compete with you and remind you of his "superiority" in conflicts. I've seen it with my kids as well.

Comment: Yeah, he does that a lot, and that is what I thought would happen when going into a middle management role working for him. I might be wrong, but I have a feeling, that he would intervene a lot with how I run the project and then tell me that I am doing things wrong, as opposed to constructively criticising me when needed because he is my older brother and thinks he knows best, despite not being a trained project manager. When we have disagreements outside of work, he generally likes to be right. He has already told me that I am wrong but not taking up the offer immediately.

Comment: @bobo2000 Let's put it that way: He is willing to pay someone who is not a "senior" at a "senior" salary. Regardless of why, this doesn't bode well for a start-up where the money is usually tight. He is either deluded or it's a false promise. None of those two options are good news for you.

Comment: He doesn't have the money right now, but if he did since he is confident in getting funding, he would do it thinking that he is doing me a favour, as Chris said, I don't think it would bode well because I will never hear the end of it working for him. "You wouldn't have got this salary elseware" etc etc then use that to probably control me.

Comment: I can't imagine him getting venture capital if his future COO has 14 months experience as a PM. Management team is one of the main things they scrutinize. No offense, but your experience isn't enough to give a VC confidence.

Comment: @bobo2000 It's not so much the fact that he currently has or hasn't the money that is relevant here: he explicitely expressed that if he had it, he would pay you twice as more than you deserve, and that's just bad as a business owner. This simple claim makes it difficult for anyone to believe him. The "use that to control me" hypothesis is also very likely. You aren't given a job out of a favor, brother or not: you are given a job and keep it because you deserve it and produce some value. Being paid should never be a favor. Don't forget that.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep of course I won't join as a COO, just product delivery, which I am actually very good at. Worked in enough start ups as a developer and now management to know how to deliver a product leanly at a good quality. What do you think my next career move should be?

Comment: @ereOn yeah I have told him that to be honest, I am not sure if it is a good idea to join any company on the bases of it as a favour since what you bring to the table will never be respected.